# How to filter and show customer based on their 1st week in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to filter customers who come in the first week only and for new customers who come for the first time in the following week will not be included.

For example, I have data like this:

| CustomerID | CustTrans | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C003 | 2022-09-03 | 36 |
| C004 | 2022-09-02 | 36 |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 | 37 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 | 37 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 | 38 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 | 39 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 | 39 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 | 39 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 | 40 |
| C005 | 2022-09-17 | 38 |
| C006 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |

For the code based on my data:

```
CREATE TABLE trydata
(
    CustomerID CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    CustTrans date,
    CustSales int,
)

INSERT INTO trydata (CustomerID, CustSales, CustTrans)
VALUES ('C001', 34, '2022-09-03'), ('C002', 23, '2022-09-02'), 
       ('C003', 132, '2022-09-03'), ('C004', 95, '2022-09-02'),
       ('C002', 68, '2022-09-08'), ('C001', 54, '2022-09-05'),
       ('C002', 34, '2022-09-11'), ('C002', 98, '2022-09-23'),
       ('C004', 34, '2022-09-19'), ('C001', 30, '2022-09-18'),
       ('C003', 34, '2022-09-26'), ('C005', 34, '2022-09-17'),
       ('C006', 34, '2022-09-25'), ('C001', 34, '2022-09-25');

ALTER TABLE trydata ADD Weeks int;

UPDATE trydata 
SET Weeks = DATEPART (week, CustTrans);
```

For the result, I hope my data will be like this

| CustomerID | CustTrans | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **C001** | 2022-09-03 | **36** |
| **C002** | 2022-09-02 | **36** |
| **C003** | 2022-09-03 | **36** |
| **C004** | 2022-09-02 | **36** |
| C002 | 2022-09-08 | 37 |
| C001 | 2022-09-05 | 37 |
| C002 | 2022-09-11 | 38 |
| C002 | 2022-09-23 | 39 |
| C004 | 2022-09-19 | 39 |
| C001 | 2022-09-18 | 39 |
| C003 | 2022-09-26 | 40 |
| C001 | 2022-09-25 | 40 |

For `customer id C005 and C006` there is no, because the 2 IDs did not appear in the first week (36th week)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using a correlation with *exists*

```
select * 
from trydata t
where exists (
  select * from trydata t2 
  where t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
    and t2.weeks = (select Min(weeks) from trydata)
);
```